# Keepalived notify script isn't executed

Tags: cluster, keepalived

I just set up the notification script in `/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf`

/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

```
global_defs {
  notification_email {
    admin@example.com
  }
  notification_email_from keepalived@example.com
  smtp_server 127.0.0.1
  smtp_connect_timeout 30
  router_id DEFAULT_ROUT_ID
}


vrrp_script notification {
  script ""
  interval
  weight
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  interface eth0
  virtual_router_id 10
  nopreempt
  state backup
  priority 110
  advert_int 1
  virtual_ipaddress {
    22.22.22.22
  }
  track_script {
    notification
  }

  notify_master "/etc/keepalived/master.sh"
  notify_backup "/etc/keepalived/backup.sh"
}
```

And Whenever the state changes, it comes out

[image]

It seems working but those shellscripts are not executed.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I've actually seen the same. I moved the lines to another location in the instance definition and then they worked....

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue too, my notify script wasn't being executed, at the end of the day, I realized SELinux was blocking my script from being run, I found this out by typing:

```
[root@server ~]# journalctl
```

so go through the output, it will give you a hint as to the command to disable SELinux so your notify script can run.
Also, I didn't use notify but

```
      notify_master "/path/to/script"
      notify_backup "/path/to/script"
```

Result from SELinux:
If you believe that keepalived should have the dac_override capability by default.
                                                 Then you should report this as a bug.
                                                 You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                                                 Do
                                                 allow this access for now by executing these commands:

```
   ausearch -c 'keepalived' --raw | audit2allow -M my-keepalived

   semodule -i my-keepalived.pp
```

Once you run these commands, restart keepalived:

```
   service keepalived restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to specify the full path (rightfully).

```
Feb 14 17:14:01 lb0-0 Keepalived_vrrp[22728]: WARNING - script `killall` resolved by path search to `/usr/bin/killall`. Please specify full path.
Feb 14 17:14:01 lb0-0 Keepalived_vrrp[22728]: Cannot find script  in path
Feb 14 17:14:01 lb0-0 Keepalived_vrrp[22728]: Disabling track script chk_haproxy since not found
```